# Custom error page on System HttpNotFound()

Tags: error-handling

In my controller I'm error checking the query string and if the ID they specify doesn't exist I want to return a 404. While the path doesn't correspond with an item in sitecore I am trying to pull an item based on this ID.

We have a working nice 404 solution now. For some reason it doesn't pick up when I `return HttpNotFound()` to show the nice error message. But it does send the correct error code. I think it's reaching the IIS error page.

```
<httpRequestBegin>
    <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="CarnegieHall.Web.Pipelines.PageNotFoundResolver, CarnegieHall.Web" />
    <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="CarnegieHall.Web.Pipelines.SetNotFoundStatusCode, CarnegieHall.Web" />
</httpRequestBegin>
  <httpRequestProcessed>
    <processor type="CarnegieHall.Web.Pipelines.SetNotFoundStatusCode, CarnegieHall.Web" />
  </httpRequestProcessed>
  <mvc.getPageItem>
    <processor
      patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteUrl, Sitecore.Mvc']"
      type="CarnegieHall.Web.Pipelines.GetFromOldContext, CarnegieHall.Web" />
  </mvc.getPageItem>
```

I think the issue is in the GetFromOldContext

```
public class GetFromOldContext : GetPageItemProcessor
{
    public override void Process(GetPageItemArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        if (ItemNotFoundStatusRepository.HasFoundItemKey())
            return;
        args.Result = Context.Item;
    }
}
```

In GetFromoldContext HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode is always 200.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue ? return a HttpNotFoundResult in a controller and change the context.item to a custom 404 item ?

Answer (score 0):

We recently stuck with this issue and add new pipeline processor for stating up the 404 status code forcefully.

Created a class -

```
public class Set404StatusCode : Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestBase
{
    public override void Execute(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        var httpContext = args.HttpContext;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode >= 500 || args.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl == "/")
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!args.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath.EndsWith(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.ItemNotFoundUrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        Log.Warn($"Page Not Found on {Sitecore.Context.Site.Name}: {httpContext.Request.RawUrl}, current status: {HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode}", this);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Page not found";
    }
}
```

And patch this to after `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndDiagnostics`

```
<processor type="Project.Test.Pipelines.HttpRequest.Set404StatusCode, Project.Test" patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndDiagnostics, Sitecore.Kernel']">
```

Try this if it works for you.

Comment: this approach doesn't seems to work. The status code is changed into 404 but the custom error page is not rendered ...

Comment: @Centiyo - This code is only for setting up status ... for 404 page you need to make custom processor